# MATLAB Matrix step plot

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have this problem that I should plot a step plot from a matrix. For example:

```
[0    0    10    20    50;

 50   100  100   300   50]
```

The second line should be the x-axis so there would be points at 50, 150, 250, 550 and 600. And the according y-values should be 0, 0, 10, 20 and 50. The function stairs(B(1,:)) gives me a step plot but it's someway off. I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

`stairs` can take in two sets of values, your `x` and your `y`.

So the first issue is that you need to define both x and y;

```
y = B(1,:);
x = B(2,:);
```

The second is that your second line is the steps along x not the actual values, and `stairs` needs.  So we need to change your x values, using `cumsum` which performs a cumulative sum. Since we have a couple of points with `y=0`, as well as calling `stairs` with two inputs I'm adding some `LineSpec` options to ensure those points are visible.

```
x = cumsum(x);
stairs(x,y, '-.xk');
```

The last point may be a little difficult to see, so you may want to adjust the axis:

```
xlim([0 700])
ylim([0 60])
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for but I'd like the y-value to start at the x-value. For example there should be a line at 10 while x is between 150 and 250.

Comment: In which case your `y` should be `[0 10 20 50 50];`.